# Calculate a rolling window weighted average on a Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm relatively new to python, and have been trying to calculate some simple rolling weighted averages across rows in a pandas data frame. I have a dataframe of observations `df` and a dataframe of weights `w`.  I create a new dataframe to hold the inner-product between these two sets of values, `dot`.

As `w` is of smaller dimension, I use a for loop to calculate the weighted average by row, of the leading rows equal to the length of `w`.

More clearly, my set-up is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], index = range(0,9))

w = pd.DataFrame([0.1,0.25,0.5], index = range(0,3))

dot = pd.DataFrame(0, columns = ['dot'], index = df.index)

for i in range(0,len(df)):
    df.loc[i] = sum(df.iloc[max(1,(i-3)):i].values * w.iloc[-min(3,(i-1)):4].values)
```

I would expect the result to be as follows (i.e. when `i = 4`)

```
dot.loc[4] = sum(df.iloc[max(1,(4-3)):4].values * w.iloc[-min(3,(4-1)):4].values)
print dot.loc[4]  #2.1
```

However, when running the for loop above, I receive the error:

`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,1) (2,1)`

Which is where I get confused - I think it must have to do with how I call `i` into `iloc`, as I don't receive shape errors when I manually calculate it, as in the example with `4` above. However, looking at other examples and documentation, I don't see why that's the case...  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try not to loop over rows.  just to get you started, get rid of the "for" while replacing `sum(df.iloc[max(1,(i-3)):i]`  with something like `df[0].rolling(3).max().fillna(1)`

Comment: thanks, I tried `df = df[0].rolling(3).apply(lambda x: sum(x*w)).fillna(1)` rather than the for loop, but a shape error still gets returned `Shape of passed values is (3, 3), indices imply (1, 3)`. I'm not sure why `df[0]` is being seen as having a `(3,3)` shape when it is one-dimensional

Comment: first comment was just on the general way to do this.  your real problem is you don't have conforming shapes of your arrays.  add a print to your for loop to print the shapes of each component (df & w) and you'll see

Comment: thank you for the help, much appreciated! along with Michoel's I've got this worked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are trying to multiply arrays of two different sizes.  For example, when  `i=0` the different parts of your for loop return

```
df.iloc[max(1,(0-3)):0].values.shape
# (0,1)

w.iloc[-min(3,(0-1)):4].values.shape    
# (2,1)
```

Which is exactly the error you are getting.  The easiest way I can think of to make the arrays multipliable is to pad your dataframe with leading zeros, using [concatenation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html).

```
df2 = pd.concat([pd.Series([0,0]),df], ignore_index=True)
df2
    0
0   0
1   0
2   0
3   1
4   2
5   3
6   4
7   5
8   6
9   7
10  8
```

While you can now use your for loop (with some minor tweaking):

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    dot.loc[i] = sum(df2.iloc[max(0,(i)):i+3].values * w.values)
```

A nicer way might be the way JohnE [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732567/calculate-a-rolling-window-weighted-average-on-a-pandas-column#comment82426133_47732567), to use the [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) and [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) functions built into pandas, there by getting rid of your for loop

```
import numpy as np
df2.rolling(3,min_periods=3).apply(lambda x: np.dot(x,w))
    0
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   0.00
3   0.50
4   1.25
5   2.10
6   2.95
7   3.80
8   4.65
9   5.50
10  6.35
```

You can also [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the first two padding rows and [reset the index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
df2.rolling(3,min_periods=3).apply(lambda x: np.dot(x,w)).drop([0,1]).reset_index(drop=True)
    0
0   0.00
1   0.50
2   1.25
3   2.10
4   2.95
5   3.80
6   4.65
7   5.50
8   6.35
```

Comment: thank you for the help, that has got it! Appreciate both your and JohnE's help